# Terminal ANSI escape codes don't work

Tags: shell, terminal, ansi-escape, arcanist

When I was using Arcanist and landing some code I found out that my terminal does not escape the colors. The `<ESC>[1;32m9912da1<ESC>[m` is supposed `32m9912da1` or something similar. Is this a problem with my terminal? Other people at my work don't find this problem.

```
Landing current branch 'some-branch'.
 TARGET  Landing onto "master", selected by following tracking branches upstream to the closest remote.
 REMOTE  Using remote "origin", selected by following tracking branches upstream to the closest remote.
 FETCH  Fetching origin/master...
These commits will be landed:

      - <ESC>[1;32m9912da1<ESC>[m some commit
      - <ESC>[1;32m687f799<ESC>[m some other commit
```

Comment: What terminal software are you using? What's the value of `$TERM`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arcanist on windows with git bash this should fix it:

```
# add the following function to your .bash_profile
function arc(){
    command arc --ansi $@|cat
}
```

For detailed instructions see: https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/04/23/phabricator-arcanist-gitbash/